# Modifying the icon of a notification

Tags: icons, thunderbird, notification

I love my Newaita icons and am a bit unhappy that e.g. the Thunderbird logo is the conventional one in the notifications of new e-mails. Would there be a way to also change the icons in the notifications?

Comment: Only if you re write the app.